# Google Calendar API create event returns 201 but no event is created

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am using the Google Calendar API to create a single occurrence event from within my Google App Engine App.

The JSON encoded event looks like this:

```
event = {"data":{
             "title": "Test Event",
             "details": "Details of test event",
             "transparency": "opaque",
             "status": "confirmed",
             "location": "My Place",
             "when": [{
                 "start": "2013-03-05T15:00:00.000Z",
                 "end": "2013-03-05T17:00:00.000Z"
             }]
}}
```

The code I'm using to add the event is:

```
def sendGCalEvent(self, event):
    scope = "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/"
    authorization_token, _ = app_identity.get_access_token(scope)
    logging.info("Using token %s to represent identity %s",
             authorization_token, app_identity.get_service_account_name())
    payload = simplejson.dumps(event)

    response = urlfetch.fetch(
        "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full",
        method=urlfetch.POST,
        payload=payload,
        headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json",
                   "Authorization": "OAuth " + authorization_token})
    if response.status_code == 201:
        result = simplejson.loads(response.content)
        logging.info("Status code was %s, and the returned event looks like %s", response.status_code, result)
        return
    raise Exception("Call failed. Status code %s. Body %s",
                response.status_code, response.content)
```

Everything seems to work, it authenticates ok, the event is posted, I get a 201 response back plus the event JSON with added fields from the calendar.

But the event isn't created, it doesn't show up on my calendar. When I go to the URL in the 'alternate link' field in the returned event data, my calendar appears with an error message saying 'event does not exist'

Any help on this would be very appreciated. I'm very new to Google's APIs so hopefully I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Never used the API, but you know that `200` is the HTTP status-ok response? I can't imagine Google would drift away from that.

Comment: @NiklasR According to [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) 201 status code is "The request has been fulfilled and resulted in a new resource being created."
From the [procotol guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_protocol#AuthOAuth) for the Calendar API:
> When you send that second POST request (or the first one in cases where there's no redirect), Calendar creates a calendar event, then returns an HTTP 201 CREATED status code, along with a copy of the new event in the form of an <entry> element or (in JSON-C) data object.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. According to the protocol guide for the Calendar API:

> To post an entry, send the following HTTP request to Calendar, using a special "default" URL (and an Authorization header; see the section on authentication above). Calendar automatically redirects the default URL to the URL of the read/write private feed of the calendar belonging to the authenticated user. (Note that you don't have to use the default URL to send a POST request to Calendar; you can specify the user ID instead of "default" if you prefer. For more information, see the Calendar feed types reference.)

```
POST https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full
```

And this did return a 201 response, but didn't add the event. However when I specified the user ID for the default user it works.

```
POST https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/user@website.com/private/full
```

I'm still not sure why the default feed doesn't work.

Comment: Turns out my biggest problem was not reading the correct documentation! While the above does work, it's from V2 of the API and we should be using V3.

Comment: If you want a brief introduction to Google Calendar API v3, check this  link:                                                                         https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/calendar/v3/python/latest/